# Why my ignite application throws exception like 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache has been closed or destroyed:'

Tags: ignite

I didnot delete cache manually,but the application throws exceptions like this time by time when cache is aprroached.

Comment: We will need more details about your use case.

Comment: Most likely, you've closed it, e.g. with a try-with-resources clause. Please share your code.